# How to update and add to subdocument list with Spring+Mongo

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-mongo

I have a document like this in a MongoDB collection:

```
{
  id : ... 
  listA:[{
          id: ...,
          thing:...,
          listB:[{...},{...}]
          },...
            ]
}
```

(The top level ID is the normal auto-generated MongoDB ID. The other ID of the subdocument object is a pseudo-ID that I've generated separately and pushed into the list)

**Questions:** I would like to (1) add to `listB` and (2) change `thing`

This object can be pretty hefty and it is possible that more than one thread might be operating on the object so I want to avoid a `findOne`, update, then `save` type of scenario.

I'd like to do this in Spring Data in a similar way that I've done a push to `listA`, i.e.

```
@Autowired
private MongoOperations operations;

public void addStuff(String id, Stuff stuff) {
    operations.updateFirst(Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id)),
            new Update().addToSet("listA", stuff), Stuffs.class);
}
```

However I'm having trouble generating the right Query/Criteria.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should try next query:

```
final Query query = new Query(new Criteria().andOperator(
        Criteria.where("_id").is("id"),
        Criteria.where("listA").elemMatch(Criteria.where("_id").is("id"))
));

final Update update = new Update().addToSet("listA.$.listB", stuff).set("listA.$.thing", "thing");

final WriteResult wr = mongoOperations.updateFirst(query, update, "collectionName");
```

Comment: thanks I'll have a go. Is it always `_id` even though the field name is `id` and not a mongo id?

Comment: @user2393012 no sure it should be your key name .where("keyName").is("value")

Answer (score 3):

I think you have mixed up 2 concepts:

- Making 2 updates in an atomic operation.
- Replacing a whole document.

I understand that you just want to update instead of replacing for performance reasons, so the accepted answer is right.

But, on the other hand, the mechanism *findOne - save* is totally thread safe, because the two updates take place on the *save* operation, when the whole document is replaced. So, if there is another thread modifying your document between the *findOne* and *save* operations, your document will be correctly replaced by the newest version. And then, of course you have a problem because the thread that replaced in second place will not be notified about the first modification, *but you also have this problem with the accepted solution*.

If you really want to avoid this type of situation, you should think of [a versioning mechanism or checking old data before updating](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/update-if-current/)