# How to achive relationship in mongodb with spring boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

How to apply a relationship one this submenu entity and when I hit the post request by menu and submenu as request body. How to generate `Submenu.id` automatically.

```
// Menu Entity
public class Menu {

    @Id long id;

    private String title;

    private String path;

    private list<Submenu> submenu;
}
```

```
// Submenu Entity
public class Submenu {

    @Id long id;

    private String title;

    private String path;
}
```

I try many ways but its is not working how mongodb relationship works.

This is my postmapping

```
@PostMapping("/menus")
public MenuItems CreateMenuItems(@RequestBody MenuItems items) {
    return menuRepository.save(items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has no relationship because it's a NoRelational database.
You don't need the @Id as much as you don't need an id inside the subdocument because it's a part of the document Menu. You can specify directly the object and it will appear as a subdocument of Menu document.
Even the Id usually is a String, because it generates an UUID by default (if not needed in long type).

Comment: I have a one more question,  How to update nested document in mongodb using spring boot. is it possible or not.

Comment: check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669418/how-to-update-and-add-to-subdocument-list-with-springmongo